# Expired - Non-Expired

Tags: meaning, word-usage, non-standard

I have to classify users, like Expired users and users who are not expired.

Shall I use the term Non-Expired to indicate that a user is still valid and has a long enough validity period?

> Is there a term like **non-expired**?

Any suggestion would be helpful!

Comment: Current, valid? Non-expired is perfectly understandable.

Comment: Active? Non-expired is fine, yeah.

Comment: You need to be careful between "active" or "current" meaning "non-expired", or meaning "has used the site recently".

Comment: @MaxWilliams - Good point; I missed that.

Comment: In my company we say "current" meaning "has a current subscription" (ie non-expired) and "active" meaning "has used the site recently".

Comment: @MaxWilliams "expired" has that same temporal quality.  If "active" is ambiguous then so is "exipred".

Comment: How does a user become "expired?"  I'd say the term is too ambiguous as is.  If we take it to a ridiculous extreme, it could even mean the user is dead so the non-expired user would just be alive.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it a naming question about computer things.

Answer (score 0):

Extant

Extant means ‘still existing’. It’s from the latin for ‘can be seen’.

You can say ‘extant users’ meaning - users who still exist or are current.  You could also use ‘existing’ but I like ‘extant’ as it means ‘still to be seen’ or ‘happening now’.

Example:

- Is Mr. Perkins still around, did he die? ‘No, he is still extant.’
- Did the building get demolished? ‘No, it is still extant’.

Extant is not specifically to do with documents existing, as is stated in a few online dictionaries. I have seen how 1 entry online appears to have spawned errors in other online dictionaries. Extant applies to anything at all, that still exists.

Extant just means ‘exists’.

So you can say ‘extant users’ to mean ‘currently valid’ existing users.

It’s true that this does not denote whether users are ‘actively using’ the system. It just means that they ‘have access’ - or not. (As noted by a commenter).

You seem to need a third term, however, to express the length of time remaining on a user subscription, as you mention a user who ‘has a long-enough validity period’.

As all this is fairly confusing and the meaning is likely to be misinterpreted among different support staff, if it were my system, I’d create a specific terminology, like green, orange and red.

Where:

- Green = current user (Extant or Existing user)
- Orange = user who is due to expire in 3 months or less (Expiring User)
- Red = user who is expired (Ex-user)

You might also consider: 
Yellow = new user and 
Blue = active or VIP user

I would define each category precisely, share it with the whole team, colour code it in the system, and then... go and have a nice cup of tea :)

You’ll see in this definition below, which is correct, in my view, the reference to ‘an extant letter’. It seems that this online dictionary entry has been misinterpreted into other dictionary entries to mean that extant ‘is about old documents’. But it ain’t!

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/extant